pyenv Can't Activate Virtualenv via zsh
I can't seem to activate a pyenv environment for some reason.  pyenv is installed and coming up with a version 2.4.19.  My .zshrc has this:
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

When I go to have a script to turn on this virtual environment: pyenv activate myenv I get an error:
Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.

But activating it manually works fine.  And deactivating it as well.  I've been having the same issues with scripting this sort of behaviour with conda, so both seem to have issues with the zsh scripting this on and off.
How can I get this to work?  It seems natural to have an alias to turn this on and off.

Have you used xtrace (aka set -x) to watch what's happening (both during the eval at load-time, and during the pyenv call at runtime)? With only the details provided, and no instructions that allow reproducing the problem on our own machines, we don't know what's going on any more than you do.

It might also be worth running which pyenv (only on zsh; on bash which isn't a builtin and can't see functions/aliases/&c so you'd need type pyenv instead) to see if you're getting a function or an executable; if it isn't a function, that tells us the content in your dotfiles didn't have the intended effect, so that would at least be a place to start.

You are talking about a script, but didn't say how you invoked the script. Also, AFIK the pyenv does not contain only of exported variables, but also of functions, and they won't be available in your script. Why don't you do the eval stuff inside your script?
